# Set of roots of sum is equal to the intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $(I_a)_{a \in A}$ be a family of ideals of $K[x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n]$.
I want to prove that:

$$V \left ( \sum_{a \in A} I_a\right )=\bigcap_{a \in A} V(I_a)$$

Do we have to use the definition:

$$V(S)=\{ (a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n) \in K^n| f_a(a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n)=0 \forall a \in A\}$$

If so, how could use it?

**EDIT**: In order to show that $V \left(  \sum_{a \in I_a}\right) \subseteq \bigcap_{a \in A} V(I_a)$ I tried the following:

Let $\overline{x} \in V\left(  \sum_{a \in I_a}\right)$.
That means that $f(\overline{x})=0 \forall f \in \sum_{a \in A} I_a$.

We want to show that $\overline{x} \in \bigcap_{a \in A} V(I_a)$, i.e. that $f(\overline{x})=0 \forall f \in I_a \subseteq \sum_{a \in A} I_A$. And thus, it holds.

Therefore $V \left(  \sum_{a \in I_a}\right) \subseteq \bigcap_{a \in A} V(I_a)$.

For the other direction I tried the following:

Let $\overline{x} \in \bigcap_{a \in A} V(I_a)$. That means that $f(\overline{x})=0, \forall f \in I_a, \forall a \in A$.

$$I_a \subseteq \sum_{a \in A} I_a$$

$$\Rightarrow f(\overline{x})=0 \forall f \in \sum_{a \in A} I_a \Rightarrow \overline{x} \in V \left (\sum_{a \in A} I_a \right )$$

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Your question "do we have to use the definition of $V(S)$?" makes me wonder whether you understand the concept of a definition...

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward but confusing.

$\subseteq$:

Suppose $x \in V(\sum I_a)$. By definition $f(x)=0$ for all $f \in \sum I_a$. But the generators of $\sum I_a$ is the union of the generators of each $I_a$, so in particular $f(x)=0$ for **each** generator of $I_a$. This means that $x \in V(I_a)$ for all $a$. So $ x \in \cap_a V(I_a)$.

$\supseteq$:

This is similar: Assume that $x \in \cap_a V(I_a)$. By definition of intersection, this means that $x \in V(I_a)$ for all $a$. Do you see the rest of the proof?

Comment: Fredrik Meyer Could you explain me why the generators of $\sum I_a$ is the union of the generators of each $I_a$  ?

Comment: $$ \supseteq : $$

We assume that $x \in \cap_{a} V(I_a)$.

By definition of intersection, that means that $x \in V(I_a), \forall a$.

By definition of $V$, we have that $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I_a, \forall a \in A$.

So, $f(x)=0, \forall f \in \sum_a I_a$.

That means that $x \in V(\sum_a I_a)$.

Therefore, $V(\sum_a I_a) \subset \cap_a V(I_a)$.

Is it right? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: @evinda That seems  correct to me! For the first question: that follows almost by definition: if $I+J$ is by definition the set of sums $i+j$ with $i \in I$ and $j \in J$.

Comment: @Frederik Meyer At the point where I say:

"we have that $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I_a, \forall a \in A$.

So, $f(x)=0, \forall f \in \sum_a I_a$."

how can I prove this?
$$$$


$$ \subseteq : $$

Let $x \in V(\sum_a I_a)$.

By definition of $V$ we have that $f(x)=0, \forall f \in \sum_a I_a$.

Does this mean that $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I_a, \forall a$?

Or do we have to use the generators as you did?